# Reactive Form Async Validator is not setting the error to the FormGroup

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

I'm doing a web application in Angular 10 with a simple form to receive two values that I will be validating them on the backend, doing a HTTP call. To accomplish this I have created an async validator which runs perfectly.

**Problem:**
It's not setting the error to the FormGroup. In other words, the FormGroup is always valid.

```
this.form = this.fb.group({
  // I will validate this two values with the backend
  patientIdentifications: this.fb.group({
    clinicRecord: [null, Validators.required],
    documentId: [null, Validators.required]
  }, {
    updateOn: 'blur',
    asyncValidators: CustomValidators.isPatientValid(this.myService) // <= async validator
  }),
  // Just to illustrate that I have more FormControls
  firstName: [null, Validators.required],
});
```

**Async validator**

```
export class CustomValidators {

  static isPatientValid(myService: MyService): AsyncValidatorFn {
    return (formGroup: FormGroup):
      Promise<ValidationErrors | null> |
      Observable<ValidationErrors | null> => {

      const clinicRecordControl = formGroup.controls.clinicRecord;
      const documentIdControl = formGroup.controls.documentId;
      const clinicRecordValue = clinicRecordControl.value;
      const documentIdValue = documentIdControl.value;

        return myService.getPatient(clinicRecordValue, documentIdValue).pipe(
          map(patient => patient ? of(null) : of({valid: true})),
          catchError(() => of(null))
        );
    };
  }

}
```

The HTTP call is done perfectly when the two inputs loses the focus. But the error is not being set in the FormGroup.

**I have tried these solutions:**

#1. Adding `bind()` to the validator call

```
patientIdentifications: this.fb.group({
        clinicRecord: [null, Validators.required],
        documentId: [null, Validators.required]
      }, {
        updateOn: 'blur',
        asyncValidators: CustomValidators.isPatientValid(this.myService).bind(this) // <= bind
      }),
```

#2. Remove the `of` function

```
return myService.getPatient(clinicRecordValue, documentIdValue).pipe(
              map(patient => patient ? null : {valid: true}), // <= remove the "of"
              catchError(() => of(null))
            );
```

#3. Setting the error directly using the FormGroup's instance

```
return myService.getPatient(clinicRecordValue, documentIdValue).pipe(
              map(patient => patient ? formGroup.setErrors(null) : formGroup.setErrors({valid: true})),
              catchError(() => of(null))
            );
```

None of the solutions have worked for me.

My goal is to set the error to the FormGroup correctly to have the FormGroup as `INVALID`, which is the correct thing to do.

Comment: Shouldn't `catchError(() => of(null))` return `of({valid: true})` since it's an error?

Comment: Also try swapping `map` for `switchMap`.

Comment: @Chrillewoodz do you mean doing `return formGroup.valueChanges.pipe(switchMap...` or returning the `switchMap` directly?

Comment: `return myService.getPatient(clinicRecordValue, documentIdValue).pipe(
          switchMap(patient => patient ? of(null) : of({valid: true})),
          catchError(() => of(null))
        );`

Comment: @Chrillewoodz Believe it or not, your first comment solved my issue, I need to return `of({valid: true})` inside of the `catchError`. Also, it works with `switchMap` or `map`, although I don't understand the difference. I know what `switchMap` is for, but never seen it used like this. Lastly, I'm not sure if the correct thing to do is `of(null)` or `formGroup.setErrors(null)`. If you could place the answer with the best approach I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right now you're saying that errors are OK since you're not returning `of({valid: true})` but rather `of(null)`. If you change it to this instead it will work:

```
return myService.getPatient(clinicRecordValue, documentIdValue).pipe(
      map(patient => patient ? of(null) : of({valid: true})),
      catchError(() => of({valid: true))
    );
};
```

Based on your comment which asks whether to return an observable or use `formGroup.setErrors(null)` I would go with an observable as it seems to be the recommended way when looking at [the docs for custom validators](https://angular.io/guide/form-validation#defining-custom-validators). This is irregardless of when you're using async or synchronous validators.